# When playing a segment with AVAudioPlayerNode can I register for two different callbacks, Scheduling Complete AND Playback Complete?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayernode

I am building a multitrack audio player in Swift using AVAudioPlayerNode. When scheduling an audio segment for playback, I want to be notified when the scheduling is complete AND when/if file playback finishes. The way the Swift API is written it appears that you can only register for one or the other. If you call the short function:

```
func scheduleSegment(_ file: AVAudioFile, 
       startingFrame startFrame: AVAudioFramePosition, 
          frameCount numberFrames: AVAudioFrameCount, 
                  at when: AVAudioTime?, 
   completionHandler: AVAudioNodeCompletionHandler? = nil)
```

The callback gets called as soon as the file has been scheduled (not played, just scheduled to be played), and you cannot pass any special arguments, just a basic closure.

When calling the fancier function, you can specify which type of callback you would like, however you must pick one and only one:

```
func scheduleSegment(_ file: AVAudioFile, 
       startingFrame startFrame: AVAudioFramePosition, 
          frameCount numberFrames: AVAudioFrameCount, 
                  at when: AVAudioTime?, 
completionCallbackType callbackType: AVAudioPlayerNodeCompletionCallbackType, 
   completionHandler: AVAudioPlayerNodeCompletionHandler? = nil)
```

The enum AVAudioPlayerNodeCompletionCallbackType can be one of the following:
dataConsumed, dataRendered, or dataPlayedBack

Unfortunately I must pick one, but really I need two. I need to be notified when scheduling is complete AND dataPlayedBack.

Is there a way to do this?